# How to query overlapping dates on Postgres DateRange field

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a model with a PostgreSQL `DateRange` field:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    date_range = DateRangeField()
```

If I want to query this to see if another date overlaps, that's easy enough:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(date_range__overlap=other_date)
```

But if I have built a list of `DateRange` objects, how can I search the list asking this same thing of the list (rather than the queryset). I.e. "Does this DateRange overlap with any of the DateRanges in this list?":

```
mylist = [DateRange([2021-10-04, 2021-10-05]), DateRange([2022-10-04, 2022-10-05])]

for dr in mylist:
    dr.overlap(query_date) # fails
```

Note: `DateRange` objects have no attribute `overlap` per [docs](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#range-data-types).

Comment: Should the queryset contain `MyModel` objects that overlaps with *any* of the `DateRanges`, or *all* of the `DateRange`s.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem any of the date ranges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that two `datetime`s do *not* overlap if *e<sub>1</sub>≤s<sub>2</sub>* or *e<sub>2</sub>≤s<sub>1</sub>* with *s<sub>i</sub>* and *e<sub>i</sub>* the start and end of fragment *i* respectively.

This thus means that the two *do* overlap in case *e<sub>1</sub>>s<sub>2</sub>* and *e<sub>2</sub>>s<sub>1</sub>*. We thus can construct an overlap check with:

```
def is_overlap(dr1, dr2):
    return dr1.upper > dr2.lower and dr2.upper > dr1.lower
```

Next we can find out if any of the items overlaps with:

```
any(is_overlap(query_date, dr) for dr in mylist)
```

or we can construct a list of all `DateRange`s that overlap with `query_date`:

```
[dr for dr in mylist if is_overlap(query_date, dr)]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to query the list, not the existing objects, unless I am mistaken?  I.e. "Does this DateRange overlap with any of the DateRanges in this list?"

Comment: It will retrieve all the `MyModel` objects that have at least overlap with one of the `DateRange`s.

Comment: Sorry I haven't been clear. I used MyModel as an example for how you can use `overlap` on querysets. I want to check if the item is overlapping with anything in the list, not existing records.

Comment: `any(map(query_date.overlap, mylist))` results in `'DateRange' object has no attribute 'overlap'`

Comment: @alias51: yes, I'm working on it :)

Comment: @alias51: the updated answer should do an overlap check between `query_date` and all `dr`s in `mylist`. If one (or more) overlaps are detected, then the `any(...)` expression will return `True`.